# Panoramio pictures on iOS without Google Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, mapkit, panoramio

I'm developing a little iOS App which shows POIs on a standard MKMapKit map (from Apple). When the user select a POI, the app send a request to Panoramio to get a photo from the latitude and the longitude, like that :

```
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=2&minx=XXXXXXXX&miny=XXXXXXXX... etc...
```

The problem is that I saw today on the Panoramio ToS :

```
http://www.panoramio.com/api/terms.html
```

> Section 2: API Client restrictions
>       You may not use the API in API Clients using map technology other than Google Maps or any photo-sharing sites.

I'm not using Google Maps API for iOS so the question is : can I use the standard MKMapKit from Apple AND show photos from Panoramio in the same app ?

If not, is there an alternative solution to get photos from GPS coordinates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, I AM NOT A LAWYER AND THIS IS NOT LEGAL ADVICE.

Disclaimer aside, use apple's CoreLocation classes to generate latitude/longitude information, and you never touch mapping software.

Geolocation and mapping are two complimentary functions that don't necessarily interact.

From what I read there, I don't see a problem with retrieving your location via the CoreLocation framework, and subsequently using that info to request map information from Panoramio.

Good luck!